# Combining express and socketIO 0.9 in Nodejs application

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have 2 working NodeJS apps. In one I am using express and the other http.createServer. I tried combining them following the documentation here
 
https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/tree/0.9.17
I am using socketIO *0.9** & express *4.11.2*.

```
   var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var multer  = require('multer'),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app,{transports:['flashsocket', 'websocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling']})
       , fs = require('fs'),
   ffmpeg =  require('./lib/fluent-ffmpeg');


var server = require('http').createServer(app)
, io = io.listen(server);

var port = Number(8080);
server.listen(port);
```

And this is the complete error message. As far as I can tell I've defined *server* exactly like the documentation.

```
Socket.IO's `listen()` method expects an `http.Server` instance
as its first parameter. Are you migrating from Express 2.x to 3.x?
If so, check out the "Socket.IO compatibility" section at:
https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x
   info  - socket.io started

/Users/foo/Documents/app.js:12
, io = io.listen(server);
          ^
TypeError: Object #<Manager> has no method 'listen'
```

Comment: Define "had no luck"; what's the specific issue? How have you tried to combine them?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you've already called `listen` on the require of `'socket.io'`, which is likely the first problem.